# Java: how to detect the current java runtime is a JRE or JDK?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I got a Java application, I want to provide user ability to compile Java source code (Using JavaCompiler interface)

If the user run the application on a JRE, my application should tell user that the no JavaCompiler instance  aviable.

so how  to detect JDK or JRE in java programe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can request an implementation of `JavaCompiler` from `ToolProvider`. If it returns `null`, there is no implementation of `JavaCompiler` available:

```
JavaCompiler c = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
if (c == null) {
    // JRE
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that works - it seems like the `JavaCompiler` interface itself is always available, but the distinction of JDK vs. JRE depends on there being an implementation.

Comment: it works great when the JDK is installed properly, and `javac` can be found on the classpath. but what if i want to allow a user to run it, even if the `javac` cannot be reached? all i want to know is if i'm running on JDK or JRE... see [this link](http://www.java.net/node/688208) - it can be solved if the user defines the environment variable. but since i have no need for the `javac`, i don't want to bother the user with this extra configuration overhead...

Comment: Not working on JDK7x64, are we sure this still works?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at stackoverflow thread - [How to determine if the Java VM is installed on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362941/how-to-determine-if-the-java-vm-is-installed-on-windows) , [How do I detect which kind of JRE is installed — 32bit vs. 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807263/how-do-i-detect-which-kind-of-jre-is-installed-32bit-vs-64bit) and [How can I detect the installed Sun JRE on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339910/how-can-i-detect-the-installed-sun-jre-on-windows)

You can use `System.getProperties()/System.getProperty()` method.